# Visual Studio ToolBox in active Even Reset Toolbox after also showing Grayed color inactive

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio 2015, when i  plan to work web application both Design and Source . i am trying to add some toolbox controls. but totally toolbox showing grayed color and inactive showing Like this

[Toolbox inactive image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v40Go.png)

I tried all method Toolbox Reset and Delete tdb Files all method  not Working. i gave Repair action its reinstall completed take more than one year after the Reboot again showing same toolbox inactive .how to Fix this issues? i need uninstall totally ? or else any  solution available ? please help me ?